# Is it possible to mod the Rangyinputs jQuery plugin to become more dynamic?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use [Rangyinputs jQuery plugin](https://github.com/timdown/rangyinputs) in 4 different textareas on my site. I have moved the jQuery code (that, in the plugin demo, is placed in the html file) to a .js file instead and included it in the head-tag. I want all 4 textareas to be able to use it dynamically because I need to have **different id:s of all the textareas** (not id="ta", which is hardcoded into the plugin). I would also prefer if I could pass the text in replaceSelectedText() and surroundSelectedText() dynamically into the functions instead of being hardcoded as it is now.

In short I want something like this (pseudo-code):

- $(document).ready(function**()** *to become*:
- $(document).ready**(function($TextareaName, $Text, $Before, $After)**

...

- $ta.replaceSelectedText("[Text]") *to become*:
- $TextareaName.replaceSelectedText($Text)
- $ta.surroundSelectedText("[Before]", "[After]") *to become*:
- $TexareaName.surroundSelectedText($Before, $After)

...

- input type="button" name="replaceSelectedTextAndCollapse" *to become*:
- input type="button" onClick="replaceSelectedTextAndCollapse($Textarea,$Text"
- input type="button" name="surroundSelectedText" *to become*:
- input type="button" onClick="surroundSelectedText($Textarea,$Before,$After)"

Since I don't even know where to start (my main interest is php, not javascript or jQuery) I'm humbly turning to this awesome community! Sorry if my pseudo-code is more php-like than jQuery-like but I hope you get what I'm after and are able to point me in the right direction. Cheers!

**head (.php file)**

```
<!-- the plugin file -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../rangyinputs-jquery-src.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery moved from the html-file (in the demo) to it's own file -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../rangyinputs.js"></script>
```

**jQuery (.js file)**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var $ta = $("#ta");
        var $startIndex = $("#startIndex"), $endIndex = $("#endIndex");

        function reportSelection() {
            var sel = $ta.getSelection();
            $startIndex.text(sel.start);
            $endIndex.text(sel.end);
        }

        $(document).on("selectionchange", reportSelection);
        $ta.on("keyup input mouseup textInput", reportSelection);

        $ta.focus();

        reportSelection();

        $("input").mousedown(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            switch (this.name) {
                case "replaceSelectedTextAndCollapse":
                    $ta.replaceSelectedText("[Text]", "collapseToEnd");
                    break;
                case "replaceSelectedTextAndSelect":
                    $ta.replaceSelectedText("[Text]", "select");
                    break;
                case "deleteText":
                    $ta.deleteText( +$('#ta_start').val(), +$('#ta_end').val() );
                    break;
                case "deleteSelectedText":
                    $ta.deleteSelectedText();
                    break;
                case "extractSelectedText":
                    alert($ta.extractSelectedText());
                    break;
                case "surroundSelectedText":
                    $ta.surroundSelectedText("[Before]", "[After]");
                    break;
                case "collapseToStart":
                    $ta.collapseSelection(true);
                    break;
                case "collapseToEnd":
                    $ta.collapseSelection(false);
                    break;
                case "setSelection":
                    $ta.setSelection( +$('#ta_start').val(), +$('#ta_end').val() );
                    break;
            }
            $ta.focus();

            // For IE, which always shifts the focus onto the button
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                $ta.focus();
            }, 0);
        });
    });
</script>
```

**buttons & textarea (.php file)**

```
<input type="button" class="unselectable" unselectable="on" name="replaceSelectedTextAndCollapse" value="paste test text">
<input type="button" class="unselectable" unselectable="on" name="replaceSelectedTextAndSelect" value="paste test text and select">
<input type="button" class="unselectable" unselectable="on" name="deleteText" value="delete text">
<input type="button" class="unselectable" unselectable="on" name="deleteSelectedText" value="delete selected text">
<input type="button" class="unselectable" unselectable="on" name="extractSelectedText" value="extract selected text">
<input type="button" class="unselectable" unselectable="on" name="surroundSelectedText" value="surround selected text">
<input type="button" class="unselectable" unselectable="on" name="collapseToStart" value="collapse to start">
<input type="button" class="unselectable" unselectable="on" name="collapseToEnd" value="collapse to end">

Select/delete text from <input type="text" id="ta_start" size="3" value="5"> to
<input type="text" id="ta_end" size="3" value="7">
<input type="button" class="unselectable" unselectable="on" name="setSelection" value="set selection">

Selection: <b id="startIndex"></b> to <b id="endIndex"></b>
<textarea rows="15" cols="80" id="ta">Some test text</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, a few things to (hopefully) guide you forward.

First, regarding `$(document).ready()`. This is a jQuery function that monitors the page load process. It will execute the function provided as a parameter once the initial document is safely loaded. Since the function you provide gets invoked by jQuery there is no way to pass parameters to it.

Consequently, your desire to do this:

`$(document).ready(function($TextareaName, $Text, $Before, $After) ...`

is not possible.

Instead, you will need to create an object that will wrap the rangyInputs commands. There are improved ways to accomplish this than what I will show, but I wanted to present the most straight-forward approach to keep it as simple as possible.

Within your `ready` function we will need to do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // additional parameters are passed to the functions as needed
    function RangyInputsWrapper(elTA) {
        var elTextArea = elTA;
        this.surroundSelectedText = function(textBefore, textAfter) {
            elTextArea.surroundSelectedText(textBefore, textAfter);
        };
        this.replaceSelectedTextAndCollapse = function(text) {
            elTextArea.replaceSelectedTextAndCollapse(text);
        };
        // additional functions to wrap the RangyInputs calls as needed
    }
    var myWrapper = new RangyInputsWrapper($("#test"));
    $("#replaceSelectedTextAndCollapse").click(function() {
        myWrapper.replaceSelectedTextAndCollapse("Substitute Text");
    });
    $("#surroundSelectedText").click(function() {
        myWrapper.surroundSelectedText("BEFORE", "AFTER");
    });
});
```

What we are doing here is creating an object `myWrapper` that remembers the text area you are trying to operate against. If you have more than one text area on a page, you can create multiple objects - just create a `myWrapper2` (or whatever you want to call it, and `new RangyInputsWrapper($("#xyz"))` to reference the respective text area with an id of `xyz`.

Now, the `myWrapper` variable has access to the functions defined by `RangyInputsWrapper`, so you can wire up your buttons with a click handler that is appropriate. I have hard-wired the text used, and would recommend you keep it that way initially until you see the substitutions taking place as expected. After that you will need to do some jQuery work within your click handlers to get the text you are interested in.

The code above assumes you have on the page the following HTML:

```
<textarea id="test" title="Test Area">A bunch of text here to experiment with.</textarea>
<input type="button" id="replaceSelectedTextAndCollapse" />
<input type="button" id="surroundSelectedText" />
```

I hope this helps get you to the next stage. I suspect your learning curve is going to be steep, but to do what you want, you are going to need to really dive into this to get your head around it.